# how to get a clicked value of the tab in php

Tags: javascript, php

when the user clicks li(tab) i need to get the value of li in post php to display the tab content which is based on the submitted value of tab

```
 <div class="row"> 
            <div class="tab">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
                            <li class="active myisp" data-value="overall" style="margin-left:1cm;" > 
                                <a href="#overall_tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"> 
                                  <span><i class="fa fa-list fa-1x text-info"></i></span> 
                                  <span>Overall</span> 
                                </a> 
                            </li> 

                    <?php $isp_tab=mysql_query("select distinct(isp) from red_dgid_info");
                        while($result=mysql_fetch_array($isp_tab))
                        { 
                        $isp_value = $result[0];
                          echo '<li class="myisp" data-value='.$isp_value.'> 
                                    <a href="#isp_value_tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false"> 
                                        <span><i class="fa fa-list fa-1x text-info"></i></span> 
                                        <span>'.$isp_value.'</span> 
                                    </a> 
                                </li> ';
                        }
                    ?>
                    </ul> 
           </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: You wanna get data value? such as `overall` `tab`?

Comment: yes in post method of php @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: make use of js to get those values inside the data attribute, then make your xmlhhtprequest and use post

Comment: LI's are simply HTML display elements, they are not form elements. As they are not form elements, they do not 'POST' data to the back end. You could add a button inside the LI which submits a form.

Comment: You can use Jquery then send them to php using ajax

Comment: `mysql_*` extensions are dangerous and deprecated since I was born...

Comment: how to make xmlhttprequest and use post @Ghost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i used the get method

```
<form method="GET" action="#" id="form_1">
```

then write the onclick funcion

```
<a href="#live_isp_tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" onclick="window.location.href=\'page_name.php?clicked='.$isp_value.'\'">
```

To get the submitted isp value in php

```
<?php $isp = $_GET['clicked']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you  just put that value into a hidden input field and post that value:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ispValue" value='.$isp_value.'>
```

and get it with

```
$_POST['ispValue'])
```

I think that's a much simpler approach.

Comment: Is there any way to get the value of a li without submitting the form @thebluefox

Comment: Use JavaScript - but this isn't my answer @puvi

Comment: by using javascript hw can i pass the value of li to another query @thebluefox

Comment: By using ajax, you can send values over to php and then: $this->request->hasPost(), GetPost().

EDIT: are you sending data to PHP or to another JS?

Comment: My point is that if you send from JS to JS define a global variable.
If you wanna send the value without submiting to php, use:
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "targeted_phpfile.php",
        data: { "variableName" : variable,}
    }); 

and use  if($this->request->isAjax()){
if($this->request->hasPost('variableName'){
      $variablephp = $this->request->getPost(' variableName');
   }
}